# I change php.ini but phpinfo() not showing changes

Tags: centos, php-ini, php

I have hosting over scaleway, centOS installed with vestacp.

I am trying to modify max_execution_time setting, i edited php.ini files via ssh but when i check the phpinfo() it shows loaded configuration file (none) and settings are not changed.

But when i check over ssh, it shows loaded configuration file as etc/php.ini

How can i make the configuration file loaded?

Thanks

Comment: Have You restarted server?

Comment: `php.ini` changes affect after restarting apache.

Comment: yes, i restarted the apache server. How can i restart the fastcgi?

Comment: nothing changed after restarting apache. But when i check over SSH i can see that etc/php.ini is loaded, but on phpinfo() it is still not loaded...

Answer (score 0):

Put this statement on top of your **script set_time_limit(40);** where 40 is number of seconds. If set to zero, no time limit is imposed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where am i going to put set_time_limit(40); ?

Comment: At top of your script.

Comment: To Which script?

Comment: <Php set_time_limit(40);

Comment: I mean to which file?

Comment: some servers don't allow you to modify the configuration file. So use this script set_time_limit in your PHP script at the top to achieve the same thing you are looking for but instead of changing in INI file you do changes in PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the answer myself :)

I changed Vesta - Web - domain.com - web template to default so php started using Apache instead CGI/FastCGI.

It successfully loaded php.ini also i can edit from vesta panel.

Regards